# Create a foreign key relationship in Entity

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have two entities:

```
class Cost {
    @OneToOne
    private String bookId;
}

class CostBook {
   private String id;
}
```

I would like to create a many to one relationship between Cost and CostBook. Many Costs can reference the same CostBook in the bookID field

**However, I cannot change CostBook class.**

I tried to put @OneToOne annotation on the bookId field, but IntelliJ immediately says :

```
'One To One' attribute type should not be 'String'
```

What is the correct way to establish the relationship?

I was thinking something like:

```
class Cost {
    @OneToOne
    private CostBook bookId;
}
```

But if I do this, does it mean I have to save a reference to CostBook anytime when I tried to save Cost?

Comment: How do you want to handle it? You can map it as a relationship (Cost having a CostBook reference) or as a basic String for the foreign key - it is up to you. What changes just might be how you setup your database, and how you have to set values, but both are valid and can work. You can even do both in the same object - map the FK as a string and with the CostBook reference, and just mark one as writable (the other insertable=false, updatable=false). You don't need to have a fully populated/managed Cost instance when persisting CostBook if using a OneToOne, but it certainly helps if you can.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. I can't merge these two classes into one so they have to be separate. Ideally, I would like to keep bookId as a string and references the id field in the CostBook. Note that I cannot make any changes to the CostBook class.

Comment: You don't need changes to CostBook at all; Cost reference costBook, so needs a FK of some nature. How you map it (oneToOne or just a String) is up to you. Your choice though then dictates how you must set that value - JPA will set the value from the references for you, something that is nice to have with using ID generation and persisting complex graphs.

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. How to implement what you suggested?

Comment: Are you using JPA for DDL/table generation or are you able to modify the scripts yourself? JPA can handle the FK as a basic mapping no problem (just remove the @OneToOne annotation on your String property and see), but won't generate the FK constraint in the DB, you'd have to do that yourself.

Comment: @Chris I am modifying the scripts myself. We use liquibase for this.